# How to block window.postMessage from parent window with different origin?

Tags: javascript, content-security-policy

I would like to stop all window.postMessage() that do not come from my website's domain.

Currently,  an outsider can open a new window to my website's URL with mySite = window.open(), then the outsider is able to send a message to my site's window with  mySite.postMessage()

Can this be stopped using Content Security Policy? Or intercept the messages with javascript?

Comment: does your site respond to `message` events without checking the origin? if not, then you should - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage#security_concerns

Comment: @JaromandaX I have a third party widget that listens to all messages. There are limited options, unless I modify the widget myself.

Comment: so, this third party widget listens to all messages from all domains? sounds like a major security flaw

Comment: There is the risk if the scripts are not properly written, hence I am trying to stop the cross origin messages